# Insert array of years into a list of URLS

Tags: awk, sed, python

I have a list of URLS like the example below.

```
/test/test
```

I also have an array of years

```
[1999, 2000, 2001].
```

I am trying to find a way to automate the task of printing out a list of URLS with the year inserted as below:

```
/test/1999/test
/test/2000/test
/test/2001/test
```

I don't need to do this in any automated way so `sed`, `awk` or `python` would all be fine!

Answer (score 1):

You specify only one "URL" the following Python program support a list of them:

```
urls = [
    '/test/test',
    ]

years = [1999, 2000, 2001]

for url in urls:
    for year in years:
        spliturl = url.split('/')
        spliturl.insert(2, str(year))
        print('/'.join(spliturl))
```

The trick is to insert the year at the second position, the first position of `spliturl` is the empty string (that is the string before the first `/`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one `bash` solution as well :

```
declare -a a=(1999 2000 2001)
url='/test/test'
for i in "${a[@]}" ; do echo "$url" | sed "s:/:/$i/:2"; done
```

Comment: you can avoid the [leaning toothpicks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) with `sed "s:/:/$i/:2"`.   Also, remember to quote your variables:  `for i in "${a[@]}" ; do echo "$url" | sed "s:/:/$i/:2" ; done`

Comment: Thanks ! excellent read. much more readable using colons as separator. I usually quote variables but when I know that it cannot contain spaces (years and urls), I tend to not quote them, that might be a bad habit

Comment: yes, a bad habit.  there are a very few situations where you do not want to and should not quote them (e.g. when you've constructed a variable containing multiple command-line options/args), but in all other cases it's best to always quote your shell variables.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
echo test/{1999,2000,2001}/test
```

or even

```
echo test/{1999..2001}/test
```